# Button issue eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, button, count, click

I want to create a simple app in eclipse with a button. I want to make it so that after the button is pushed 10 times a message will pop up. The problem is that when I start the app and push the button 10 times , nothing happens. Could you please tell me what I've done wrong?

Here's my activity file:

```
package com.example.dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
public class Game extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        Button gamebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gamebutton);
    }
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int clicked = 0;
        clicked++;
        if(  clicked==10){
            AlertDialog.Builder gamebuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(Game.this);
            gamebuild.setMessage("Good");
            gamebuild.setCancelable(false);
            gamebuild.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Game.this.finish();

                }
            });
            gamebuild.setNegativeButton("One more!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();        
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks for response! I've edited the activity file this way:

```
package com.example.dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class Game extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
    int clicked = 0;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        Button gamebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gamebutton);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        clicked++;
        if(  clicked==10){
            AlertDialog.Builder gamebuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(Game.this);
            gamebuild.setMessage("Good");
            gamebuild.setCancelable(false);
            gamebuild.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Game.this.finish();

                }
            });
            gamebuild.setNegativeButton("One more!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();        
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Still it's not working in a proper way. Sorry for dumb questions: I'm new to android.

new edit:

```
package com.example.dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class Game extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
    int clicked = 0;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        Button gamebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gamebutton);
        gamebutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v){
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub

        clicked++;
        if(  clicked==10){
            AlertDialog.Builder gamebuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(Game.this);
            gamebuild.setMessage("Good");
            gamebuild.setCancelable(false);
            gamebuild.setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Game.this.finish();

                }
            });
            gamebuild.setNegativeButton("One more!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();        
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the counter inside the onClick function, causing it to reset every time. So, move

```
int clicked = 0;
```

from inside the onClick to before your onCreate such as:

```
int clicked = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate....
```

This will make it set to 0 once, then stay equal to whatever it's last value was as long as the app is open and not killed.

Comment: thanks for repsonse! i've edited the activity file, as you've said, but it is still not working in a proper way. I've added the new activity-file code in my question. Are there any more mistakes? Thanks in advance

Comment: @user3365831 You need to add "gamebutton.setOnClickListener(this);" in order to tell the button what function to call on click. Because you are doing this, you may want the onClick function to check the view (passed as v) to check which button is being pressed so that you can have more than one button (if you want, plus it's good practice)

Comment: could you please see the question once again - I edited it again. I've tried puttin' "gamebutton.setOnClickListener(this)" both inside and outside of onClick. still no changes.. thanks a lot

Comment: @user3365831 Hmm, strange. Try adding log traces to check what is happening. For example, in your onClick try doing "Log.d("Game", clicked);" after you add to clicked. It should show the current number of clicks. If nit doesn't show in LogCat when you click, then the onClick isn't working. Otherwise, check to make sure that clicked is increasing. We can go from there.

Comment: @user3365831 found it! You aren't showing the dialog. You need to call gamebuild.show();

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that variable *clicked* is declared inside onClick. So it's always zero. You have to declare it globally, inside class Game.